# Hard coding data during import

Tags: import, contributions

I'm trying to import some contribution information from our payment processor and need to specify a "financial type" for the Civi Contribution (A mandatory field).

Unfortunately, this information isn't contained in the exported data. Is there any way to hard code the value that I would like to use for all imports?

I'm thinking I'll have to pre-process the exported data to add the field, but if there is a better way to do this in Civi, that would be amazing.

Thanks!
Trev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you'll have to add a column -> with Financial Type to your Exported Data before you can import it into CiviCRM; First you make the Financial Type in your CiviCRM -> if you're not sure what these monies make a Financial Type: Legacy Monies; Then create a Financial Type column in your Exported Data -> and fill it with: Legacy Monies. That should work - and will not take too long!

Comment: Sort of buried in this is kind of a enhancement suggestion.  If one is having to import data from a payment processor every month, it would be nice not to have to add the column every month.  The concept being on import you could select a financial type that all the imported contribution get.  Of course, enhancements need someone to do it and it's hard to know just how many people actually do an import like this every month and would therefore use it.

Comment: Most people will use a Payment Processor with CiviCRM and will not need to import contributions from elsewhere every month

Comment: Thanks! Would be a cool enhancement to be able to hard code data during all imports (i.e. not just CiviContribute) but as Paul said - would need some resource!